# How to combine Ionic Segment and Slide to make swipe-able tabs with Ionic-React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ion-slides, ion-segment

I am new to Ionic and having problem to combine IonSegment and IonSlides in my Ionic-React application. There are not much resources in the internet especially using with Ionic with React. How do I get the index of the slide content (in this case a Card component) which will also change the content to the next segment (from Market to My Package or vice versa). Or is there any better way to achieve this?
Here's the code below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {IonSegment,IonSegmentButton,IonRow,IonCol,IonGrid,IonContent,IonSlides, IonSlide,IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar,IonButtons,IonMenuButton,IonSearchbar} from '@ionic/react';
import Card from '../components/Card';
//import Segment from '../components/Segment';
const Market: React.FC = () => {

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  const slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    speed: 400,
    loop: false,
    pagination: {
      el: null
    },
  
  };

 
return (
<IonPage>

<IonHeader>
  <IonToolbar>
    <IonButtons slot="start">
      <IonMenuButton />
    </IonButtons>
    <IonTitle>Market</IonTitle>
  </IonToolbar>
</IonHeader>

<IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Search Package</IonTitle>
          <IonSearchbar value={searchText} onIonChange={e => setSearchText(e.detail.value!)}></IonSearchbar>
          {/*-- Segment in a toolbar --*/}
          <IonSegment onIonChange={e => console.log('Segment selected', e.detail.value)}>
            <IonSegmentButton value="market">
              <IonTitle>Market</IonTitle>
            </IonSegmentButton>
            <IonSegmentButton value="mypackage">
              <IonTitle>My Package</IonTitle>
            </IonSegmentButton>
          </IonSegment>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      
      <IonContent>
      {/*-- Market Segment --*/}
      <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOpts}>
      <IonSlide>
      <IonGrid>
      <IonRow>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
      </IonRow>
      </IonGrid>
      </IonSlide>
      {/*-- Package Segment --*/}
      <IonSlide>
      <IonGrid>
      <IonRow>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
      </IonRow>
      </IonGrid>
      </IonSlide>
    </IonSlides>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
)
}

export default Market;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  // added useRef 
  import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
  import {IonSegment,IonSegmentButton,IonRow,IonCol,IonGrid,IonContent,IonSlides, 
          IonSlide,IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, 
          IonToolbar,IonButtons,IonMenuButton,IonSearchbar} from '@ionic/react';
  import Card from '../components/Card';

  //import Segment from '../components/Segment';
  const Market: React.FC = () => {

    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

    // a ref variable to handle the current slider
    const slider = useRef<HTMLIonSlidesElement>(null);
    // a state value to bind segment value
    const [value, setValue] = useState("0");

    const slideOpts = {
      initialSlide: 0,
      speed: 400,
      loop: false,
      pagination: {
        el: null
      },
    
    };

    // a function to handle the segment changes
    const handleSegmentChange = (e: any) => {
      setValue(e.detail.value);
      slider.current!.slideTo(e.detail.value);
    };

    // a function to handle the slider changes
    const handleSlideChange = async (event: any) => {
      let index: number = 0;
      await event.target.getActiveIndex().then((value: any) => (index=value));
      setValue(''+index)
    }

   
  return (
  <IonPage>

  <IonHeader>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonButtons slot="start">
        <IonMenuButton />
      </IonButtons>
      <IonTitle>Market</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>

  <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle>Search Package</IonTitle>
            <IonSearchbar value={searchText} onIonChange={e => setSearchText(e.detail.value!)}></IonSearchbar>
            {/*-- Segment in a toolbar --*/}
            {/*-- the value is binded to state value and is updated every time setValue is running --*/}
            {/*-- buttons values are set to 0 and 1, to match slider index, it can be whatever you need but there mas be a table --*/}
            <IonSegment value={value} onIonChange={(e) => handleSegmentChange(e)} >
              <IonSegmentButton value="0">
                <IonTitle>Market</IonTitle>
              </IonSegmentButton>
              <IonSegmentButton value="1">
                <IonTitle>My Package</IonTitle>
              </IonSegmentButton>
            </IonSegment>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        
        <IonContent>
        {/*-- Market Segment --*/}
      {/*-- the ref method binds this slider to slider variable --*/}
        <IonSlides pager={true} options={slideOpts} onIonSlideDidChange={(e) => handleSlideChange(e)} ref={slider}>>
        <IonSlide>
        <IonGrid>
        <IonRow>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
        </IonSlide>
        {/*-- Package Segment --*/}
        <IonSlide>
        <IonGrid>
        <IonRow>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
          <IonCol><Card/></IonCol>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
        </IonSlide>
      </IonSlides>
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
  )
  }

  export default Market;
```